# Need to fix drywall - ceiling speaker mounts not flush

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall, drywall-mud

New construction home, builder allowed me to install ceiling speaker mounts prior to drywalling.  I returned after drywall was installed, and because the mounts didn’t allow the drywall to sit flush, they simply cut around the entire bracket vs the interior cut out that the speaker would mount/insert into. Now, if I mount the speaker, the perimeter of bracket is visible.  I’ll try to attach a photo, but what would be the best way to patch this?

[image]

Comment: maybe a pic of the speaker installed onto the bracket could help.  confil and tape might work.  is the portion you want to cover everything except the open hole?  my low volt guy just left the speaker cable loops in the general area and we cut the hole after using the template.  i used russ sound speakers - what are you using?  i still ended up them as I didn't like the symmetry so had to patch that.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger I think the hole in the background is of a "good" installation—the bracket is more recessed than the drywall, so it covers the rim of the bracket.  The one in the foreground is proud of the (back of the) drywall.  IDK why the drywaller didn't just reset the bracket, or ask the OP to do so when it was discovered to be proud.

Comment: How does the bracket mount to framing?

Answer (score 0):

[Confill](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/cgc-synko-concrete-fill-wall-and-ceiling-compound-15-kg-bag/1000163329) and tape or backer and patch.  You could also get a speaker that doesn't require that mount.

[image: patched speaker holes]